# How to hide an adorner?

Tags: .net, wpf, adorner, adornerlayer, adornerdecorator

I have tried to hide/show an adorner of a specific element:

1)  by trying to hide the adorned element, but with no success.

2)  by using the following code, but when i apply it to the specific element, all other adorners are hidden (the elements are placed on different canvases).

```
Public Shared Sub ChangeAdornerLabelLineVisibility(ByRef line As Line, ByVal isAdornerVisible As Boolean)

    Dim lineAdornerLayer As AdornerLayer

    Try

        lineAdornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(line)

        If isAdornerVisible Then

            lineAdornerLayer.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible

        Else

            lineAdornerLayer.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden

        End If

    Catch

    End Try

End Sub
```

How can i hide the adorner of a specific element?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldnt be hiding the adornerlayer, instead you should just remove the adorner from the adorner layer and it will disappear.

For example you have an adorner as below

```
LineAdorner adorner = new LineAdorner();
lineAdornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(line)
//To Show the Adorner
lineAdornerLayer.Add(adorner);
//To hide the Adorner
lineAdornerLayer.Remove(adorner);
```

sorry i used c# syntax I am sure you can convert that to vb. Let me know if there is any problem